# How did Bill guess future Bill & Ted didn't write that song?

Tags: bill-and-ted

In *Bill & Ted Face the Music (2020)*, Bill & Ted travel to future to 2022 San Dimas California, steal the song from their
future Bill & Ted:

> Bill: Dude, I think we came too early. **These other us's don't have
> the song**.

How did Bill guess future Bill & Ted didn't write that song?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because their future selves are playing a cover song at the La Bonita Hotel and Bar on 'Open Mic Night' to a packed audience of about four people.

The implication is that if they'd written the best song in the universe, they wouldn't be doing that.